# Rails 4 - strong parameters concept involvement in spree-2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, spree, ruby-2.0, strong-parameters

How to add new fields for spree::user in Spree-2.1 + Rails4 ?

Like my old customization:
  ==========================

Spree::User.class_eval do

```
attr_accessible :f_name, :l_name :gender
validates :f_name, :presence => true, :length => {:maximum => 25}
validates :l_name, :presence => true, :length => {:maximum => 20}
```

end

new work with strong parameters:
 ================================

module Spree
    UserRegistrationsController.class_eval do

```
private
 def spree_user_params
   params.require(:spree_user).permit(:f_name, :l_name)
 end

end
```

end

Even though its not working as it got rollback..

Please let me know your comments.

Comment: Please format your code using 4 space indentation.

Comment: its giving the Unpermitted parameters: email, password, password_confirmation. i hope those are permitted in actual spree_auth_devise- registration controller.

Answer (score 13):

A change was recently made to spree_auth_devise which will allow you to set permitted attributes for Spree::User.

This is the relevant line of code:
https://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise/blob/ac27effb5998e5875261f08655e442461a031370/app/controllers/spree/user_registrations_controller.rb#L69

You'll need to add f_name and l_name to Spree::PermittedAttributes.user_attributes like so:

```
# in an initializer
Spree::PermittedAttributes.user_attributes << :f_name
Spree::PermittedAttributes.user_attributes << :l_name
```

More information about Spree::PermittedAttributes can be found in this pull request:

https://github.com/spree/spree/pull/3566

Comment: Spree::PermittedAttributes.user_attributes.push :first_name, :last_name

Answer (score 1):

@gmacdougall is right, however I want to note that if you're doing this in an extension, you may want to do this via a decorator. Your extension would have to define this in an initializer that is installed by the user via a generator, which cannot be maintained.

```
# lib/spree/permitted_attributes_decorator.rb
Spree::PermittedAttributes.class_eval do
  @@user_attributes.push(:f_name, :l_name)
end
```

You can add new attributes for many models in the [Spree:PermittedAttributes](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/e2bd38d4/core/lib/spree/permitted_attributes.rb) module. Spree controllers obtain these attributes via the methods included by the [Spree::Core::ControllerHelpers::StrongParameters](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/e2bd38d4/core/lib/spree/core/controller_helpers/strong_parameters.rb) module.

Comment: how do you verify this approach works? for the initializer approach you can `rails c`

`2.1.2 :003 > Spree::PermittedAttributes.user_attributes
 => [:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :firstname, :lastname] `

however, with the decorator approach you mention the attributes do not show

Comment: How to override view of registration view for that?