# Custom Spree Devise Registration - Admin Authorization Failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, spree, spree-auth-devise

I have added name, surname and birthdate fields to devise registration.
Here is the link to my original question.

[Adding name to Spree Devise registration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31481746/adding-name-to-spree-devise-registration)

It seems that on the frontend side everything works. However I now get an **Authorization Failure** alert when I try to access my admin.

Here is the console log:

```
Started GET "/admin/orders" for ::1 at 2015-07-21 13:25:16 -0500
Processing by Spree::Admin::OrdersController#index as HTML
  Spree::Preference Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "spree_preferences".* FROM "spree_preferences" WHERE "spree_preferences"."key" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["key", "spree/backend_configuration/locale"]]
  Spree::User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "spree_users".* FROM "spree_users" WHERE "spree_users"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "spree_users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "spree_users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 6]]
   (0.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "spree_roles" INNER JOIN "spree_roles_users" ON "spree_roles"."id" = "spree_roles_users"."role_id" WHERE "spree_roles_users"."user_id" = $1 AND "spree_roles"."name" = $2  [["user_id", 6], ["name", "admin"]]
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/unauthorized
Completed 302 Found in 88ms (ActiveRecord: 4.1ms)
```

I have tried to override **app/controllers/spree/admin/users_controller_decorator.rb**

```
module Spree
  module Admin
   UsersController.class_eval do

    private
     def user_params
         params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :spree_role_ids, :name, :surname, :birthdate)

     end

   end
  end
end
```

Comment: I think, If you already added these 3 fields in the user permitted attributes in the configuration, you don't have to override the user controller because it already uses permitted_user_attributes.

Comment: Yes but for additional fields like name etc he has override user controller or in any where in initializer her has permit additional fileds like,
Spree::PermittedAttributes.user_attributes << :name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Cant asign a role admin to any user from  frontend side.
Please register a user from front end and change it role from backend.

Comment: I just created a new admin user and entered the admin without any problem. Not sure why my existing admin user lost his privileges.

Answer (score 1):

When you register a user from front-end, it is a simple user he is not an admin or he have not admin rights that why you are facing this issue.

If you want to create a user which have admin access then you simply go to admin panel and give permissions to that users.

This is the default command to create admin, run this command in console

```
bundle exec rake spree_auth:admin:create
```

Thanks